# How can I use ViewFlipper like a slider

Tags: android, slider, viewflipper

I have a layout for recyclerview adapter that it's like a instagram. That means it has a slider for images and like button and etc.

Now I want to load multiple images in the slider and clients should change images with dragging like instagram exactly.

First I used PosterSlider library, but its problem is that doesn't have scale type so I cannot manage images size.

So now I wanna try ViewFLipper, but my problem is I don't know how can I use ViewFlipper like a slider.

That means how can I change images by dragging in ViewFLipper?

If you have another idea for changing picture, I will be glad to hear it.

This is my code for ViewFlipper that I know it is wrong, because it shows just one Image and it doesn't have any code for changing picture by dragging:

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(newsLetterList.get(position).Jsonsrc);
            for(int i = 0;i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                setImageInFlipper(jsonArray.getString(i),holder);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

setImageInFLipper method:

```
private void setImageInFlipper(String imgUrl,NewsLetterViewHolder holder){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(imageView);
        holder.slider.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take some reference from [here](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/viewflipper). They have implemented the same viewflipper slide both with next(flip) button and without using any button. Hope that helps!